# How to have a specific format for an EditText (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: android

I was wondering how I could have an EditText, in which the user has to type in the specific format of "dd/mm/yyyy". I have already used the "datetime" inputType but this only changes the keys on the keyboard.

Comment: This control looks like what you are looking for [https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889502/how-to-mask-an-edittext-to-show-the-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html You could use this to format the data/time on the go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this to your Oncreate

```
    et5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Do Nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Do Nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ss =input_Dob.getText().toString();
            int o = 0;

            if ((ss.charAt(2) == '/') && (ss.charAt(4) == '/')) {
            Toast.makeText(Create_An_Account.this, "Format Is right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                tv5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tv5.setText("Invalid Format");


            }
            ss = "";


        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way that this could be done is to type a hint in this `EditText`, that will be visualized like DD/MM/YYYY, so that the user can enter it in that format (hinted). I don't thin kthere's a way to force it like you want. You can enter the separate components, like a a separate field for DD, MM and YYYY and have constraints on those, then concatenate etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this in Oncreate.
```

Suppose that edit text id is edittext1 .

et1=(EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.editText1)

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Add Here whatever you want to do before text changed
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

}

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

/*My below example is to check email that it must contain .com & @ */

```
            ss ="oooo"+input_Email.getText().toString();

            a = ss.length();
            a--;
            int o = 0;

            if ((ss.charAt(a) == 'm') && (ss.charAt(a - 1) == 'o')
                    && (ss.charAt(a - 2) == 'c')
                    && (ss.charAt(a - 3) == '.')) {
                o = 1;
                while (a >= 0) {
                    aa = ss.charAt(a);
                    if (aa == '@' || aa == '.') {
                        j++;
                    }
                    a--;
                }
            }
            if ((j >= 2) && (o == 1)) {
                tv8.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv8.setText("Correct");
                Email_Check="Correct";
            } else {
                tv8.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tv8.setText("Invalid Email Address");
                Email_Check="Invalid";

            }
            ss = "";

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex

> "[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}"

and validate the user input and force user to enter in dd/mm/yyyy format.

But If you want to do this dynamically means convert user input automatically as soon as he enters date into dd/mm/yyyy format) then you have to customize your edit text view and implement custom input filter where you have to write the logic.

Comment: This didnt work. user could put in as many characters as they wanted still