# Text Watcher, Erase Moves text to the left

Tags: java, android, date, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

In my App I have a few edit texts for dates

I then Have a text watcher to force the format of DD/MM/YYYY

I also have a a few lines of code to automatically enter the current date

**Auto Date code**

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String date = dateF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        dateText.setText(date);
```

Now My problem is with the text watcher lets say you enter 02/12/2019

and you want to erase the day(02 in this case) you click on the 02 and press backspace

But then for this example if you have 02/12/2019 and you try to erase the 02 you get 01/22/019Y so the digits 
moves to the left and the cursor jumps to the end of the text like 01/22/019 **|** Y

So What I want to happen is when you select the text and you erase you only erase the selected text IE the day, month or year in DD/MM/YYYY

**Code for my Text Watcher**

```
TextWatcher DateWatcher= new TextWatcher() {

            @Override

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")

            @Override

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {

                    String clean = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]|\\.", "");

                    String cleanC = current.replaceAll("[^\\d.]|\\.", "");

                    int cl = clean.length();

                    int sel = cl;

                    for (int i = 2; i <= cl && i < 6; i += 2) {

                        sel++;
                    }

                    if (clean.equals(cleanC)) sel--;

                    if (clean.length() < 8){
                        clean = clean + ddmmyyyy.substring(clean.length());
                    }

                    else{

                        int day  = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(0,2));

                        int mon  = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(2,4));

                        int year = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(4,8));

                        mon = mon < 1 ? 1 : mon > 12 ? 12 : mon;

                        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon-1);

                        year = (year<1900)?1900:(year>2100)?2100:year;

                        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

                        day = (day > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE))? cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE):day;

                        clean = String.format("%02d%02d%02d",day, mon, year);

                    }

                    clean = String.format("%s/%s/%s", clean.substring(0, 2),

                            clean.substring(2, 4),

                            clean.substring(4, 8));

                    sel = sel < 0 ? 0 : sel;

                    current = clean;

                    FromDate.setText(current);

                    FromDate.setSelection(sel < current.length() ? sel : current.length());

                }

            }

            private String current="";

            private String ddmmyyyy="DDMMYYYY";

            private Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: why not use three EditText instead of just one?

Comment: Firstly for the UI, and the text in the edit text gets passed to a URL for uploading data

Comment: have you viewed this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889502/how-to-mask-an-edittext-to-show-the-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format

Comment: Yes, That is the post i used to make the text watcher in the first place

Comment: I had this problem too, and what i ended up doing was a `DatePickerDialog` that is launched when i click the EditText, this way the user doesnt delete or write manually any date, they select it from the picker, and when it is selected and the dialog is dismissed, i take the year, month and dayOfMonth given by the      `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` and write them on the EditText with the format i need.

Comment: Was Thinking about that aswell thank you, But my bosses doesn't want a dialog