# Is there a way to prefill aTextInputEditText with fixed characters?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputedittext

For example, if my `TextInputEditText` is a date.

Can I prefill the field with "-" like that "  -  -    " so the users just have to type `mmddyyyy` to get `mm-dd-yyyy` ?

This is just an example, I need other patterns too, so it would be nice if I can create custom ones.

I'm not talking about hints, the "-" must stay.

I tried inputType but it just changes the keyboard.

I guess I could just break my fields like "  "-"  "-"    " but I'm expecting a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you have the option of using a date-picker?

Comment: This question is alredy answered. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889502/14327871