# For material design date time picker, is it possible to add input masking to the inbuilt textfield for entering date?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

For material date picker textfield for entering date, does it allow you to customize it such that it will automatically add / after 2 digits, example: the date 02/22/1955, so if i enter 22 then it will automatically add / followed by me entering 22 . after which it will add / and finally the year.
basically like this : ( currently i have to manually enter / after the digits)
[image]

Comment: Do you want to do it automatically?

Comment: yeah, i wanna do it automatically as in it should auto enter as i go add in digits

Comment: Can [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889502/how-to-mask-an-edittext-to-show-the-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format) help you ? My code is show calendar and select the date on the calendar.

Comment: i wonder if its possible to update material design component, override their default component somehow. Its possible to easily customize the regular native date picker but material design seems to be very restricted, just wondering how to override existing layouts and code/functions for material design date picker somehow

Comment: Based on this [issue ticket](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/939), I think you are looking at modifying: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/SingleDateSelector.java Realize that edge cases exist (like what do you see when you remove the date, but not month or year) as noted in @hungcuiga1 link.

Comment: but is it even possible to update the material design view to show input masking?